# Текст возле лого

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста как расположить текст по середине картинки - как дополнение к лого (обтекание что-ли)
[image: вот пример как задумано]

```
<div class="logo">
   <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" id="foo" class="rounded-circle">
   <p class="fw-bold ">Test1</p>
   <p class="fw-bold text-danger">Test2</p>
</div>
```

```
.logo {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#foo {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Пробовал с установкой стилевого свойства float со значением right.не понимаю почему но не помогло. Test 1 u test2 просто становятся в ряд

Comment: Напр. для logo `.logo { display: flex; }` и оба p с текстом завернуть в div.. Способов море есть, не ленитесь гуглить это крайне легко сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Обернул тексты в div]

Обернул тексты в div.
Но на сколько это правильно?

```css
.logo {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#foo {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.text1 {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.text2 {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" id="foo" class="rounded-circle">
  <div class="text1 d-flex">
    <p class="fw-bold ">Test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text2 d-flex">
    <p class="fw-bold text-danger">Test2</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

С конкретной настройкой придется немножко повозится. Но основное решение заключается в добавлении `shape-outside` — [свойство](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) которое задает различные формы при обтекании. Для размещения текста я использовал `br` исключительно для простоты (как и спаны вместо параграфов), и размеры увеличил чтобы был заметен эффект.

```css
.logo {
   margin-left: 20px;
}

#foo {
   float:left;
   shape-outside: circle(50%);
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
   <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" id="foo" class="rounded-circle">
   <br>
   <br>
   <span class="fw-bold ">Test1</span>
   <br>
   <span class="fw-bold text-danger">Test2</span>
</div>
```